# How to get input value and pass it to angular component?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and trying to create a simple todo app.

I used [(ngModel)] to pass the input value to the component but it seems i am doing it in incorrect way.

This is my code

**HTML:**

```
<div class="todo-app">
  <h1>Todo List</h1>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter your task" autofocus="" [(ngModel)]="value">
    <button class="btn" (click)="addTodo()">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.styl']
})

export class AppComponent {
  todos = [];
  id:number = 0;

  addTodo() {
    this.todos = [...this.todos, {title: this.value, id: this.id++, completed: false}];
    return this.todos;
  }

  removeTodo(id:number) {
   return this.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id)
  }

  toggleCompletionState(id:number) {
    this.todos.map(todo => todo.id === id ? {...todo, completed: !todo.completed} : todo)
  }

  getAllTodos() {
    return this.todos;
  }
}
```

What is wrong here and why **ngModel** doesn't work??

Comment: You forgot to declare your `value` field. This should work though (however, it's a bit weird to store a single value as a property when you'll have several of them). Anyway, please elaborate on what your issue is.

Comment: i am confused, i do not even know how to get the input value and pass it to the component to use it, can you please show me a demo how to achieve that??

Answer (score 5):

> On your template since you had assign **value** on your ngModel, declare it also on your Component to be able to access its instance there.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" 
       class="input" 
       placeholder="Enter your task"
       [(ngModel)]="value">        // this 'value' must be instantiated on your component
```

**Component**

```
@Component({...}) {

   value: string;                  // Add this as you had used and assign it to your ngModel

   addTodo() {
      console.log(this.value);     // this will now have a value depends on your input from ngModel
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because

```
 [(ngModel)]="someFieldInComponent"
```

and you dont have `someFieldInComponent` in your component (`value` field in your case)

Comment: i added the field now and nothing worked!!, the input and the button even not shown on the page don't know why?

Comment: prepare stackblitz

Comment: @Antoniossss Even though it's invalid to not declare the field from typescript's compiler's perspective, it still translates to valid JS (since you don't have to declare it in JS). So the issue has to be elsewhere.

Comment: i can not get you, i have an issue when i use ```[(ngModel)]="value"``` with the input, it disappears, don't know why?

Comment: @Jeto i only read *What is wrong here and why ngModel doesn't work* and saw no field.

Comment: And idk who is saying anything about disapearing fields here ;(

Comment: @Antoniossss input is not rendered on the page after adding ngModel directive

Comment: Maybe you got some exceptions? All in all, in case of normal usage, there is no way that ngmodel can affect visibility, unless misuse causing rendering to fail for some reasons. Moreover there is not a clue why would that happen in your question (nor statement that it is not rendering anywhere). Just reproduce on stackblitz and let ppl help you on real code. Otherwise it is just waste of everybody's time

Comment: The problem was in addition to i forgot the value field in the component was i had to import FormsModule!

Comment: And obviously you had exception in the console